# Firebase Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 error

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase to register a new user on the web platform,
The registration works well and I can see the new user in Firebase console.

But when I check some errors during the registration like duplicate mail for example, I get an error in the dev tools console:

`www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=.. iucensg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()`

This is my code, hope you can help:

```
 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, $scope.password).then((user) => {

            firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function (idToken) {

                var providerID = user.providerData["0"].providerId;

                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: url + '/userReg',
                    data: {
                        firstName: $scope.firstName,
                        lastName: $scope.lastName,
                        providerID
                    },
                    headers: {'x-auth': idToken},
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                    if (response.status == 200) {
                        // $scope.$emit('logoutEvent', true);
                        $sessionStorage.put('ActiveUser', {accToken: idToken, providerID: 'email'});
                        $scope.$parent.logoutShow = true;
                        $scope.$parent.diaryShow = true;
                        $scope.$parent.userShow = true;
                        $scope.$parent.signInShow = false;
                        $scope.$parent.registerShow = false;
                        $window.location.href = '#/diary';
                    }

                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                });

            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

        }).catch(function (error) {
            $scope.alertShow = true;
            $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
        })
```

Comment: your enabled auth sign in method firebase console ?

Comment: I enabled the email/password there if that is what you mean

Comment: Can we see your index.html scripts?

Answer (score 8):

If catch error

[image]

Solution is change word "public" to "build"

[image]

Original

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

change to

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Change `index.html` from

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

to

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Result run success without error

[image]

Comment: That worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 5):

Did you change under authentication tab under advanced settings :
One account per email address: Allow creation of multiple accounts with the same email address? Try checking that and see if that's a problem.